# How to create a YUM proxy with Nexus OSS on Windows

Tags: windows-7, open-source, nexus, yum

Version: Nexus OSS 2.11.2-03
OS: Windows 7 Professional
Error: "createrepo" not available and "mergerepo" not available

For clarity sake, I am trying to create a yum proxy using Nexus OSS on Windows7.

Now, I get it that creating a yum repo/proxy on windows is a bit counter intuitive, but that's what I'm being "asked" to do. If it really just is not possible, then let me know.

I had thought that Nexus OSS came with yum support out of the box, but I'm having some problems.

I do not have "yum" as one of the available repository types when I create a new proxy.

In the Administration->Capabilities screen, I see the above error/warning.

Comment: That does help, but this is more of a "Nexus OSS setup and administration" question than a "How does YUM work" question. My task is to proxy the public RHEL, centos and epel repositories so we don't have to manually update our local repositories.

Comment: Either you have local mirrors or you don't. (I mean technically you could have local metadata and remote RPMs but that's not a very useful setup.) In any case if you are just trying to have your clients use the upstream repositories why have them go through you at all? Or, conversely, if you want them to go through you but use the upstream repos as data sources why not just redirect or actually just proxy the repo? Why set up a local repo at all?

Comment: The reason to use the proxy is due to firewall rules on a closed network. I have no choice as to where and on which operating system Nexus is hosted, and I absolutely have to go through the Nexus proxy to get to those upstream repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nexus yum support in Nexus 2 relies on the native createrepo and mergerepo commands. As such it needs to be run on a OS that allows these tools to be installed.

Read more about this in the [yum chapter of the Nexus documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/yum.html).

[Nexus 3](https://support.sonatype.com/forums/23079216-Nexus-3-Milestone-Releases) no longer relies on these native tools for YUM repositories, and is production ready.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know if there is a target release date?

Comment: Later this year. And the yum integration will continue to be part of Nexus OSS of course.

Comment: That should be acceptable. I'm not in production state, so I'll be happy to use the milestone.

Comment: I have a feeling that was added after the latest milestone.. send me an email at manfred at sonatype dot come so I can follow up in the next days.

Comment: Does Nexus OSS 3 support Yum (natively)? The documentation at http://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype and the "Repository Create" menu in the GUI only lists only Docker NuGet npm Bower ...

Comment: There is no support for yum in Nexus Repository Manager 3 at this stage. It is coming though.

Comment: @ManfredMoser where can I find more info about the state of YUM in nexus?

Comment: You will have to ask Sonatype. I dont know at this stage.